# Python join line by key from txt file

Tags: python

Hi I want to join line in txt file by Key in python, tried to get the 1st line with 'H' and join 'L' with the S820098509 in the 1st set of data for example.

I have the following

```
H,REPPTY,S820098509,C,S,909688,820001,20181023,20181108,20181205,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",PLANOGRAM PO,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098509,0007,RCM4PCDUOTBLK,347,,,,20181108,20181205,7.8,AUD,A5381060,SET,1
L,REPPTY,S820098509,0018,RCMRBRRNRGRY,246,,,,20181108,20181205,5.1,AUD,A5381079,EACH,1
L,REPPTY,S820098509,0020,RCM2PCRAWGRY,246,,,,20181108,20181205,2.8,AUD,A5381083,SET,1
H,REPPTY,S820098691,C,O,909357,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098691,0062,6PK1300RB,24,,,,20181114,20181211,2.32,AUD,A9437132,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098695,C,O,909513,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098695,0004,MTAP50EL5,226,,,,20181114,20181211,21.4,AUD,A5349617,EACH,1
L,REPPTY,S820098695,0005,MTAP50AL1,344,,,,20181114,20181211,3.3,AUD,A5349618,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098704,C,O,909903,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098704,0004,JTE229,32,,,,20181114,20181211,4.07,AUD,A9404146,EACH,1
L,REPPTY,S820098704,0040,JBJ7513,33,,,,20181114,20181211,5.38,AUD,A9430524,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098742,C,O,909613,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNTAO AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098742,0030,DF7475S,70,,,,20181114,20181211,23.52,AUD,A9485074,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098875,C,O,909520,820001,20181101,20181120,20181217,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098875,0052,RST158,72,,,,20181120,20181217,1.69,AUD,A9417626,EACH,36
L,REPPTY,S820098875,0055,RST176,36,,,,20181120,20181217,3.63,AUD,A9445084,EACH,36
H,REPPTY,S820099023,C,O,909352,820001,20181102,20181120,20181217,"FOB CNTAO AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820099023,0072,DB1940TS,15,,,,20181120,20181217,11.77,AUD,A9447563,SET,5
```

I want to join them to look like this.

```
REPPTY,S820098509,C,S,909688,820001,20181023,20181108,20181205,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",PLANOGRAM PO,N,,,0007,RCM4PCDUOTBLK,347,,,,20181108,20181205,7.8,AUD,A5381060,SET,1
REPPTY,S820098509,C,S,909688,820001,20181023,20181108,20181205,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",PLANOGRAM PO,N,,,0018,RCMRBRRNRGRY,246,,,,20181108,20181205,5.1,AUD,A5381079,EACH,1
REPPTY,S820098509,C,S,909688,820001,20181023,20181108,20181205,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",PLANOGRAM PO,N,,,S820098509,0020,RCM2PCRAWGRY,246,,,,20181108,20181205,2.8,AUD,A5381083,SET,1
REPPTY,S820098691,C,O,909357,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",,N,,,0062,6PK1300RB,24,,,,20181114,20181211,2.32,AUD,A9437132,EACH,1
REPPTY,S820098695,C,O,909513,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,0004,MTAP50EL5,226,,,,20181114,20181211,21.4,AUD,A5349617,EACH,1
REPPTY,S820098695,C,O,909513,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,0005,MTAP50AL1,344,,,,20181114,20181211,3.3,AUD,A5349618,EACH,1
REPPTY,S820098704,C,O,909903,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,0004,JTE229,32,,,,20181114,20181211,4.07,AUD,A9404146,EACH,1
REPPTY,S820098704,C,O,909903,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,0040,JBJ7513,33,,,,20181114,20181211,5.38,AUD,A9430524,EACH,1
REPPTY,S820098742,C,O,909613,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNTAO AUSYD        ",,N,,,0030,DF7475S,70,,,,20181114,20181211,23.52,AUD,A9485074,EACH,1
REPPTY,S820098875,C,O,909520,820001,20181101,20181120,20181217,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,0052,RST158,72,,,,20181120,20181217,1.69,AUD,A9417626,EACH,36
REPPTY,S820098875,C,O,909520,820001,20181101,20181120,20181217,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,0055,RST176,36,,,,20181120,20181217,3.63,AUD,A9445084,EACH,36
REPPTY,S820099023,C,O,909352,820001,20181102,20181120,20181217,"FOB CNTAO AUSYD        ",,N,,,0072,DB1940TS,15,,,,20181120,20181217,11.77,AUD,A9447563,SET,5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list is ordered, this is a very simple example of finite state machine: each `H` redefines the head, each `L` is a new output line. You shoud the `csv`module to parse the data:

```
import io
import csv

DATA = """H,REPPTY,S820098509,C,S,909688,820001,20181023,20181108,20181205,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",PLANOGRAM PO,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098509,0007,RCM4PCDUOTBLK,347,,,,20181108,20181205,7.8,AUD,A5381060,SET,1
L,REPPTY,S820098509,0018,RCMRBRRNRGRY,246,,,,20181108,20181205,5.1,AUD,A5381079,EACH,1
L,REPPTY,S820098509,0020,RCM2PCRAWGRY,246,,,,20181108,20181205,2.8,AUD,A5381083,SET,1
H,REPPTY,S820098691,C,O,909357,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNNGB AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098691,0062,6PK1300RB,24,,,,20181114,20181211,2.32,AUD,A9437132,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098695,C,O,909513,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098695,0004,MTAP50EL5,226,,,,20181114,20181211,21.4,AUD,A5349617,EACH,1
L,REPPTY,S820098695,0005,MTAP50AL1,344,,,,20181114,20181211,3.3,AUD,A5349618,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098704,C,O,909903,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098704,0004,JTE229,32,,,,20181114,20181211,4.07,AUD,A9404146,EACH,1
L,REPPTY,S820098704,0040,JBJ7513,33,,,,20181114,20181211,5.38,AUD,A9430524,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098742,C,O,909613,820001,20181029,20181114,20181211,"FOB CNTAO AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098742,0030,DF7475S,70,,,,20181114,20181211,23.52,AUD,A9485074,EACH,1
H,REPPTY,S820098875,C,O,909520,820001,20181101,20181120,20181217,"FOB CNSHA AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820098875,0052,RST158,72,,,,20181120,20181217,1.69,AUD,A9417626,EACH,36
L,REPPTY,S820098875,0055,RST176,36,,,,20181120,20181217,3.63,AUD,A9445084,EACH,36
H,REPPTY,S820099023,C,O,909352,820001,20181102,20181120,20181217,"FOB CNTAO AUSYD        ",,N,,,
L,REPPTY,S820099023,0072,DB1940TS,15,,,,20181120,20181217,11.77,AUD,A9447563,SET,5"""

# two pseudo-files, source and destination
s = io.StringIO(DATA) # use `with open(..., 'r') as s:` if you have a file
d = io.StringIO() # use with open(..., 'w') as 

reader = csv.reader(s)
writer = csv.writer(d)

header = []
for row in reader:
    if row[0] == "H": # a header
        header = row[1:] # store it
    else: # a line
        assert header[:2] == row[1:3] # check the identifier
        writer.writerow(head + row[3:]) # merge rows

print(d.getvalue()) # content of the pseudo-file
```

Note: you have a comma more, between header and lines, because we merge the both lists.

If the lines do not follow the headers, you'll have to store the lines and the headers in some dictionary.